# Migrating Windows Backup to another backup tool

Tags: windows-7, backup, migration

For about two years to date, I have been "piloting" monthly incremental backups with Windows Backup.

Today, though, my pilot has come to a close as my home server has been drained completely of disk space, and no drive bays are left to add on my RAID 5 (the server is quite old, and the highest capacity drive in it is 70 GB). I could attach a larger USB drive and redirect the network share to it, but it would decrease the reliability of the backups.

I have resolved that Windows Backup is such a lame tool to use, since it only places backup files in Zip archives and only compresses "recognized" formats like `.doc` and `.txt`.

How can I stop using Windows Backup, migrate my two years' worth of content, and start using another, more intuitive tool? Is there any backup software that allows this migration to occur easily? Or do I just have to suck it up and either keep using Windows Backup at the peril of drive failure or start over from scratch?

Comment: You seem to have used data backup and not imaging. Imaging is the better tool because it creates files that you can mount (VHD or MRIMG). Imaging has the added advantage that it compresses everything. I would use use Windows imaging, free Macrium or free AOMEI Backupper. Or if you want real simple, use the Wbadmin command. If you want the data only, it should be in a separate data partition.

Comment: @whs Problem is that I want to only backup specific directories as 200 GB of my drive is devoted to Steam games and some Fraps footage.

Comment: Can you separate those out into a separate partition ?

Comment: @whs No, that would require an intrusive resize..

Comment: What's intrusive about a resize. Just shrink a partition where you have spare room.

Comment: @whs MFT is at the end of the drive. You can't move the MFT without an aggressive/lengthy defrag.

Comment: Use partition wizard bootable CD. That will move the mft when you shrink. ==> http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html Just have patience. It may take a while to move the data around.

Comment: @whs Hmm, okay. Thank you for your advice. You are welcome to post it as an answer.

Comment: Nah, that's OK. Main thing is that you have a workable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a year, I decided to suck it up and migrate to Clonezilla. Shadow copies are still accessible after restoring from a backup, so whether or not it is incremental is of minimal importance. Clonezilla also compresses data much better than Windows Backup could ever do.

I will now zip up these old backups and archive them somewhere.